# kineticJS createImageHitRegion for sprites, not images

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am using [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) and wish to create a precise image hit region (ignore transparent pixels) for my sprites. I see how [createImageHitRegion accomplishes this for images](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-pixel-detection-with-kineticjs/), but I don't see how to apply this to sprites. Said another way, while method createImageHitRegion is a method which accomplishes what I want for images, there appears no similar method for sprites. If I could create an image hit region on just one image of each of my sprite that could work for me, but a big rectangular region which encompasses the entire width and height of the image of the sprite can't work. Any ideas for a workaround? Perhaps I've missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way hit-test non-transparent pixels on sprites.

I can think of a couple of theoretical workarounds...

**If you can draw a path outlining the pixels you want to hit.**

The sprite object allows a custom `drawHitFunc` so you could use `mySprite.afterFrame` to redefine a custom hit area for each of your sprite images.

```
mySprite.afterFrame(0, function() {
    mySprite.setDrawHitFunc(function(){
        // draw the path you want used for frame#0 
    });
});

// repeat for all frames
```

**If you can't draw a path outlining the pixels you want to hit.**

Instead of using sprites, make your own sprites using individual images.

Do that by creating a series of images (including createImageHitRegion) and sequentially making one of those images visible so it appears to be playing a spritesheet.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the drawHitFunc before. This seems perfect as it's easy in Inkscape to create paths outlining the pixels. Thanks!